# Connecting to localDb in a unit test throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, localdb

I have a VS2013 project that talks to a Sql Server database, using EF6.1.  To date, I've been running some automated tests using the [Effort](https://effort.codeplex.com/) in-memory database.

I'm experimenting with using Sql Server's LocalDb, instead, and I'm running into problems I don't understand.

- From with VS's Server Explorer, I created a new connection to a LocalDb database, and through it I created a new database, then
- I brought up the properties window on the database, in Server Explorer, and copied the Connecting String to my clipboard, then
- I pasted this connection string into the ConnectionString element of my test assembly's App.config,
- I ran one of the tests.

I get:

```
System.ArgumentException: "Keyword not supported: 'data source'".
```

My connection string is simple:

```
<add name="MyDbContext" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=localDb;Integrated Security=True" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
    />
```

And my code is equally simple:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestCustomers
{
    private MyDbContext myDbContext = null;

    private IEnumerable<customer> defaultCustomers = new []
        {
            new customer{customerid = "Customer 1"},
            new customer{customerid = "Customer 2"},
            new customer{customerid = "Customer 3"},
        };

    [TestInitialize]
    public void init()
    {
        this.myDbContext = new MyDbContext();

        foreach (var customer in this.defaultCustomers)
            this.myDbContext.customers.Add(customer);
        this.myDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void testAllCustomers()
    {
        var customers = this.myDbContext.customers;
        var customerList = customers.ToList();
        Assert.IsTrue(customerList.Count == 3);
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: EF connection strings are a different format. See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404268/keyword-not-supported-data-source

Comment: That question had the right answer.  I needed to replace the "provider connection string" section of the EF connection string with what the localDb property pages was giving me, not replace the entire EF connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the provider as `System.Data.EntityClient` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`. Both of those require different connection string formats.

A good source for working out what to use is http://www.connectionstrings.com