# Error: Keyword not supported: 'data source' when creating EntityConnection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to initialize EntityConnection but getting following error:

> **Keyword not supported: 'data source'."**

I am using this connection string.

```
<add name="Model1" connectionString="data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=PSB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Have you tried `Data Source`? Note the Capital letters.

Comment: Yes, I tried but no luck.

Comment: Try the below question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404268/keyword-not-supported-data-source