# Set Connection String at Runtime - EF Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Try to have a connection string during at runtime or remove it from App.config.However I am getting an error.

fyi: EF 6 CodeFirst

```
public class DfDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DfDbContext()
        : base(GetConnectionString())
    {

    }


    private static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = "xxxxx";
        builder.InitialCatalog = "xxxx";
        builder.UserID = "xxx";
        builder.Password = "xxxx";
        builder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
        builder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
        return builder.ConnectionString.ToString();

    }
}
```

Error

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.

Any alternative solution?

Comment: Data source is the name of the server. InitialCatalog is which database on that server. (For SQL Server.)

Comment: Oh, that's probably it. From that connection string, EF has no way to know that you are talking to a SQL Server database. How do you tell EF what database type you are using so that it knows how to interpret the connection string?

Comment: What happens if you pass in an open connection instead of a connection string? (Yea I'm guessing, but it sounds like it should work.)

Comment: [`EntityConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.113).aspx)?

Comment: May be add builder.Provider  = "System.Data.SqlClient"; For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: MetaData is required on EntityConnectionStringBuilder

Comment: I believe there no MetaData on CodeFirst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! Setting the default connection factory!

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

With the following DbContext.

```
public class Model : DbContext
{
    public Model()
        : base(ConnectionString())
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

    private static string ConnectionString()
    {
        // logic here
        return "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=xx;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=xx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
    }
}
```

Comment: the connection string set in xml is not reading rather it is hard code in model function. can we use defaultConnectionFactory  tag in app.config file ? how to read it from code ?

Answer (score 0):

With reference from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404268/keyword-not-supported-data-source). A valid connection string should be as follows

```
<add name="XXXX" 
     connectionString="Data Source=MONTGOMERY-XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Integrated Security=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I think you have missed out Provider name. Try adding it and check