# Windows Form Application System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException InnerException :ArgumentException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public AddressExamples.AddressBookEntities db = new AddressExamples.AddressBookEntities();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                db.Addresses
                                .OrderBy(entry => entry.LastName)
                                .ThenBy(entry => entry.FirstName)
                                .Load();

                addressBindingSource.DataSource = db.Addresses.Local;
            
            

        }

        private void addressBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Validate();
            addressBindingSource.EndEdit();
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch(DbEntityValidationException)

            {
                MessageBox.Show("help");
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my connection string:

```
    <add name="AddressBookEntities"
  connectionString="metadata=res://*/AddressModel.csdl|res://*/AddressModel.ssdl|res://*/Ad
dressModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data
source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\AddressBook.mdf;integrated
security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is the error :
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.'
InnerException:ArgumnentException : key word doesnt support :'data source'

Comment: Please try to paste the error text here. Is your connection string correct? (the error seems to be related to it being incorrect - syntax or user/password)

Comment: https://memegenerator.net/img/images/300x300/16804870.jpg Please read [ask] and translate your error message and show that you have researched it. There appears to be a problem with your connection string, show all relevant details, including your connection string.

Comment: ı added connection string

Comment: @Seval Mercan, please refer to the first answer of the question of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404268/keyword-not-supported-data-source](keyword not supported data source) to modify your connection string.

Comment: @Seval Mercan, please refer to the first answer of the question of [not supported data source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404442/11507778) to modify your connection string.