# System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'data source'.'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i keep getting this error and tried to delete the data source but that gave me another error and also tried to add another connection string also did not work how can i fix this?
https://ibb.co/4sVbnZt

```
 DbsCarEntities1 dbs = new DbsCarEntities1();
    string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbsCarEntities1"].ConnectionString;

   public ActionResult Admin1()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Admin1(Admin x)
    {
        string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbsCarEntities1"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(maincon);
        string sqlquery = "select UserName,Password from [dbo].[Admin] where UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password";
        sqlcon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlcon);
        sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", x.UserName);
        sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", x.Password);
        SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            Session["UserName"] = x.UserName.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("Main2");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Admin Login Details Does NOT match our data records!";
        }

        sqlcon.Close();
        return View();
    }
    
    public ActionResult Main2()
    {

        return View(dbs.Cars.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full text/screenshot of the error please.

Comment: @Quarter https://ibb.co/4sVbnZt

Comment: seems like a bad connection string, can you post it ?

Comment: Your connection string is not valid for EF. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404442/1131979

Comment: @ModarNa <add name="DbsCarEntities1" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\hamza\source\repos\CarSaleProjectUsingMVCandDataBase\CarSaleProjectUsingMVCandDataBase\App_Data\DbsCar.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: @CagriD.Kaynar new error Keyword not supported: 'metadata'. is there a fix for this or should i do the project again to something that support EF

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the provider name to `System.Data.SqlClient` from `System.Data.EntityClient` in your connection.I think it will resolve your issue.

```
<add name="DbsCarEntities1" 
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\hamza\source\repos\CarSaleProjectUsingMVCandDataBase\CarSaleProjectUsingMVCandDataBase\App_Data\DbsCar.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```